# How do I retrieve the sum of values within a date range without Crystal Reports summing up every value in that column?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

My goal is to retrieve the sum of all transactions carried out by a business over a period of time which can be specified by the user.

The transactions are stored on a table which holds a decimal value accompanied with a date.

See an example below

```
ID Amt Date  
1  120.0 19/05/1991  
2  240.0 31/06/1991  
3  143.0  12/07/1991  
4  69.0  02/02/1992
```

I created a date range parameter and included a running total formula in my report but every time I run the report, it always retrieves the total of all amts even if only a subset of the records are returned by the date range.

The ideal situation would be one in which the sum of all transactions returned only adds up amounts that fall within the specified date range.

Thanks.

Comment: Example with expected result would help.

Comment: are you using the date range parameters in record selection expert?

Comment: could you please post your record selection formula, so we can see if you are properly filtering the report.